# how to enable MFSideMenu in a part of view area instead of full view screen?

Tags: ios

I am using MFSideMenu which likes facebook iOS app style, it works fine! Is it possible to enable MFSideMenu for pan gesture in left 1/3 area of view instead of full view screen?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use delegate `IIViewDeckControllerDelegate`
so set the

```
[deckController setPanningMode:IIViewDeckDelegatePanning];
```

and implement:

```
- (BOOL)viewDeckController:(IIViewDeckController*)viewDeckController shouldPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGestureRecognizer
{
    if ([panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view].x<20) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Er, the OP is asking a question about MFSideMenu, and your reply applies to Inferis/ViewDeck - sounds like a glitch in the matrix..